# Import Data from .text file using Multithread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to load big size data from a .text file using Java. But because the file is very big, I would like to use multithread for this operation.
Could you help me about it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to read about [asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as this one is too broad to answer.

Comment: Not only is it too broad, it also doesn't show any research effort - which is a requirement for a good question on SO.

Comment: Flagged for removal. Too broad.

Answer (score 1):

This is not likely to yield the performance benefits that you expect. Reading from the disk is the slowest operation in the chain of retrieving data, storing it in memory, and processing the information on the CPU. Fetching data from the same file on the same disk between two or more concurrent processes will almost certainly be slower than reading from start to finish in a single thread.

Again, multithreading abstracts the CPU into concurrent threads. If the CPU isn't the bottleneck in your application then concurrency is going to be a confusing and unhelpful nightmare.

Still, since you ask:
 - you may be able to split your data using multiple files, or
 - you may be able to divide-and-conquer the input data concurrently if portions of it require extensive processing.

For instance, if each line of input text requires an expensive parse operation then you should be able to read them all into an array and then parse sections of your array in parallel.